# "Set theory" founded on lists rather than sets

Tags: lo.logic

On a computer, sets are often represented rather "indirectly / implicitly", e.g. in terms of some properties that they or their members satisfy. But some sets can be represented more "directly / explicitly",  in the sense that the representation either directly contains, or gives an algorithm for enumerating, a representation of every individual element of the set. I realize that might still be quite a vague distinction, but hopefully it'll be clear enough for what follows.

Any "directly represented" set must of course be countable, and hence well-orderable regardless of one's stance on the axiom of choice. But more than that, the representation of the set must actually come with a particular well-ordering, since the elements must be represented or enumerated in some order regardless of whether that order is actually used for anything else. It's possible to some extent to work with such direct representations of sets without caring about the ordering, but one must first define an appropriate notion of equivalence up to reordering.

What would happen if we made such (implicitly) well-ordered countable sets the basis for a form of set theory, insisting on some sort of ω-rule to avoid ω-inconsistency, and then treated uncountable sets e.g. as proper classes, or as sets whose only properties we can discuss are those pertaining to their well-ordered countable subsets [edit: or quotients]? Has such a theory been characterized?

- What would we still be able to prove? What statements would definitely be independent of such a theory?
- What about statements in-between, where the definiteness depended on the precise formulation of the theory?
- What kinds of nonstandard models could such a theory have?

---

Edit: I realize that one possible ambiguity is which countable well-orders are allowed in this theory. My intended meaning was that only well-ordered sets of type ≤ω would be given a priori, but at least some ordinals larger than this could be modelled in the sense that if X has given order-type ω then we can construct X×X, also with given order-type ω (via e.g. Cantor's pairing function) and then construct a well-ordering relation on X×X of type ω<sup>2</sup>, say.

Comment: Regarding downvotes: I accept that this question may be below research level or even poorly-defined, but would appreciate some feedback in the form of pointers to literature / textbooks, or a clarification of where the ambiguity lies so that I can try to resolve what question I really meant to ask. Thanks.

Comment: John McCarthy would be proud. :-P

Comment: actually your question is, in my modest opinion, very interesting. In a way sets are not the most basic entities: they are equivalence classes of lists up to re-ordering. Would be nice to have a precise characterization of set theory along these lines....

Comment: @AsafKaragila I did notice the connection with Lisp, which is part of the reason I feel like someone else must have done this decades ago.

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci yes, that was more or less my motivation for wondering about this. I'm glad you agree!

Comment: There is a weak notion of categorical foundations known as a 'list-arithmetic pretopos', which is one way of formalising Joyal's never published proposition for a notion called by him 'arithmetic universe'.

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci:  Would Deiser's paper, "An axiomatic theory of well-orderings", cited by Prof. Geschke in his answer below be an acceptable reference in answer to your recent question on mathoverflow?

Comment: Also, to anyone:  is there a Russell paradox associated with lists?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Yes: there is no list of all lists, since if there were, we could form the sublist of lists not having themselves as an entry, and then this list would appear on itself if and only if it didn't.

Comment: On the other hand, it should be easy enough to construct a ramified hierarchy of (countable) lists, and to my mind this construction seems more naturally founded on lists than sets.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins:  Thanks for that comment.  It reminds me (somewhat)  of a favorite quote from Jan Mycielski (from his paper "Russel's Paradox and Hilbert's  (Much Forgotten) View of Set Theory"):  "...sets are imagined boxes intended to contain other boxes.  Of course, we cannot enclose a box into itself.  And hence the class of all boxes cannot be put into one box, and the class of Russell is a superbox designed to contain all boxes."  I find it interesting that the notion of _list_  (which to me  is naively the antithesis of 'box') can be construed as yet another 'box' from which the

Comment: (cont.) paradox can be derived....

Comment: Surely a list is, in some sense, just a one-dimensional box?

Comment: @RobinSaunders:  In some sense, yes.  But then, in some sense, every predicate $\mathrm P$($\mathrm x$) forms a 'box'.  What, then, is one to make of the following argument of Russell's (from his letter to Frege, in _van Heijenoort_,  pp. 124-5):  "Let  $\mathscr w$ be the predicate:  to be a predicate that cannot be predicated of itself.  Can $\mathscr w$ be predicated of itself?  From each answer the opposite follows."  Ought we (as Russell does, in his letter) to conclude that  "$\mathscr w$ is not a predicate"?  Can there be a set/proper class distinction for lists (since there exist

Comment: (cont.) predicates which cannot be predicated of themselves)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin as Joel said, if you assume that any predicate has a corresponding "list" then a "list" containing all (ordinary) lists which do not contain themselves would have to be something analogous to a proper class. This is exactly like the situation with sets (or "boxes"), which is why I found your understanding of *list* as the antithesis of *box* surprising.

(continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) In some sense, though, a "list" of all lists satisfying predicate P has to "get its order from somewhere" (assuming that all one is given at the beginning is ordinary lists with a predefined order), and the most obvious place to get that order would be from the order on a "list" of *all* (ordinary) lists. Where does that order, in turn, come from? I'm reasonably happy with defining a canonical (well-)order on the "list" of all *countable* lists, but after that, I'm not so sure. (continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) Then again, maybe that just comes from my general discomfort with uncountable things, which is part of what motivated my interest in building things from (countable) ordered lists in the first place.

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci  "In a way sets are not the most basic entities: they are equivalence classes of lists up to re-ordering", However, you still need sets to form the equivalence classes, right?

Comment: @AnduinWilde the way I have formulated it yes. But that was only a convenient way of talking. Sets are perfectly defined types in most programming languages,  but those languages know zero of ZFC and the like. They do know how to determine whether two lists are the same up to re-ordering, though. From a computational standpoints sets are not the most primitive entities, binary strings are

Answer (score 7):

[O. Deiser, An axiomatic theory of well-orderings, Rev. Symb. Logic 4, No. 2, 186-204 (2011)] discusses an approach to the foundations of mathematics with lists as the primary objects.  It turns out that the expressive power of the new theory is the same as ordinary set theory, i.e., ZFC, if I remember correctly.  Note, however, that this theory allows for uncountable wellorderings.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Does that mean that what I've described above is equivalent to something like ZFC - powerset + "all sets are countable", perhaps with an appropriate weakening of the comprehension schema or something like that?

Comment: I am not really qualified to answer this as I don't remember any details, but I would assume that you are correct.